# Stopping a currently running thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a manager class that has created a thread for an execute method of a member.

```
 int Task::Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            setTaskSeqByName();
            for (int i = 0; i < mTaskSequence.size(); i++)
            {
                if(mCurrentStatus == "running")
                    mTaskSequence[i]->Execute();
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception ex)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I would like to be able to run it a different thread so I would be able to execute a stop that will change the `mCurrentStatus` variable so the loop will stop as well as the `mTaskSequence[i]` task.

What is the best way to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pause or stop a running thread in theory. Achieving fine grain control over another running thread is a challenge. However, using condition-variable , you can simulate one as shown below:

```
#include "conio.h"
#include <iostream>    
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

class foo_t
{
private:
    atomic<bool>& running_;
    thread worker_;
    mutex lock_;
    condition_variable signal_;
    atomic<bool> pause_;

public:
    foo_t(atomic<bool>& running): running_(running)
    {
        pause_ = false;
        worker_ = thread([&]() { run(); });
    }

    ~foo_t()
    {
        worker_.join();
    }       

};
```

The methods and properties:

```
void foo_t::run()
        {
            while (running_)
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> lock(lock_);
                signal_.wait(lock, [&]() { return !running_ || !pause_;  });
                if (!running_) return;

                cout << ".  ";
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
            }
        }

condition_variable& foo_t::GetSignal()
        {
            return signal_;
        }

void foo_t::SetPause(bool flag)
        {
            pause_ = flag;
        }
```

Main program

```
int main()
{    
    atomic<bool> running = true;

    foo_t foo(running);
    char ch;

    cout << "Press r to Run   Press p to Pause or Press to Exit \n ";

    while ( (ch = getch()) != 'p' || ch !='r'  || ch != 'x')
    {
        if (ch == 'p' )
        {
            cout << "paused\n ";
            foo.SetPause(true);
            foo.GetSignal().notify_one();
        }
        else
            if (ch == 'r' )
            {
                cout << "running\n ";
                foo.SetPause(false);
                foo.GetSignal().notify_one();
            }
            else
                if (ch == 'x')
            {
                running = false;
                foo.GetSignal().notify_one();
                break;
            }    
    }
    running = false;
    return 0;
}
```